# construct optimal transport plan from a dual optimizer

Tags: duality-theorems, optimal-transport

Consider the Kantorovich formulation of optimal transport:
$$
\inf_{\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)} \int c(x,y)d\pi 
$$
whose dual problem is 
$$
\sup_{\phi} \int \phi(x)d\mu + \int \phi^c(y) d\nu.
$$

Now, suppose I have a dual optimizer $\phi$. My question: how can I construct a optimal transport plan $\pi$ from it(without any regularity assumptions on $\mu$ and $\nu$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the best thing you can do is construct the support of the optimal plan. Meaning, given a source $x$ determine the subset of $y$'s which it is transported to, and given a target $y$ determine the subset of $x$'s which are transported to it.